# Spiking value inside a loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am writing a code to identify the proper dataset from the options in an array fits better to a given value, as below:

```
import numpy as np

def find_nearest(array, value):
        array = np.asarray(array)
        idx = (np.abs(array - value)).argmin()
        return array[idx]


thickness = np.array([0.1,0.2,0.4,0.8,1.6,3.2,6.4,12.8,25.6,51.2])
b=np.array([])
a=100
c = 48.4
while c>=0 and a>0.1:
    a = find_nearest(thickness,c)

    if a > c:
        g = np.where(thickness==a)
        f = g[0]-1
        a = thickness[f]
    else:
        a = a
    c = c - a
    print(c)
    if c == 0.1:
        break
    b=np.append(b,a)
    itemindex = np.where(thickness==a)
    itemindex = itemindex[0]
    upper_limit = len(thickness)+1
    hj = np.arange(itemindex,upper_limit)
    thickness = np.delete(thickness,hj, None)
    print(thickness)
slots_sum = np.sum(b)
print("It will be used the following slots: ",b, "representing a total of {:.2f} mm".format(slots_sum))
```

However, for some reason that could not figured out, when the codes try to find the proper combination of values to reach 48.4, the code skips the in the array the value 0.4 and select 0.2 and 0.1, which results in the sum of 48.3 instead of the correct 48.4. I am banging my head for some days, I will appreciate any help.

````
[22.8]
[ 0.1  0.2  0.4  0.8  1.6  3.2  6.4 12.8]
[10.]
[0.1 0.2 0.4 0.8 1.6 3.2 6.4]
[3.6]
[0.1 0.2 0.4 0.8 1.6 3.2]
[0.4]
[0.1 0.2 0.4 0.8 1.6]
[0.2]
[0.1]
[0.1]
[]
It will be used the following slots:  [25.6 12.8  6.4  3.2  0.2  0.1] representing a total of 48.30 mm.
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Multiply your inputs by 10 to give integer values and the answer is what you expect.

You will need to compensate for the inexact nature of floating point values if you want to compare the sums of two different lists of floating point values.